# Zooming in and out a panel using jscrollbar in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, zooming, jscrollpane

Input :- ArrayList of point2d of a geometrical shape

and transformin it as:

```
private void SetScale1(Graphics2D gr, int gr_width , int gr_height, double left_x , double right_x , double top_y , double bottom_y ){
    Rectangle2D drawing_rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(left_x, top_y, right_x - left_x, bottom_y - top_y);
  drawing_cx=(left_x+ right_x) / 2;
  drawing_cy =(top_y + bottom_y) / 2;

 at= AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance( -1* drawing_cx,  -1*drawing_cy);
//gr.translate(-1 * drawing_cx, -1 * drawing_cy);
//gr.TranslateTransform(0, 0)
double scale_x=gr_width / drawing_rect.getWidth();
double scale_y=gr_height / Math.abs(drawing_rect.getHeight());

scale_x = Math.min(scale_x, scale_y);
scale_y = scale_x;
scale_x = Math.abs(scale_x);
// at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale_x, -1 * scale_y);

gr.scale(Math.round(scale_x), Math.round( scale_y));
//gr.scale(1.2, 1.2);
//gr.transform(tt);
gr.transform(at);

//' Translate to center over the drawing area.
 graphics_cx =gr_width / 2;
 graphics_cy = gr_height / 2;
gr.translate(graphics_cx, graphics_cy);
//
}
```

:======and displayin on a panel

i want to zoomin to locate a perticular point and select it from some operations..

Kindly help me find a solution on how to zoom in out this Jpanel.....

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719085/how-to-zoom-in-to-jpanel-without-moving-the-center-math-or-swing/12719389#12719389)

Answer (score 0):

I you want to zoom in to a specific location, the easiest approach is to first translate to that location, then scale accordingly, and finally translate back.